# how to load a different application.properties file in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am using the following annotations in my spring boot testing files

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // tells JUnit to run using Spring’s testing support.
@SpringBootTest // is saying “bootstrap with Spring Boot’s support” (e.g. load application.properties and give me all the Spring Boot goodness)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

When I test rest controllers, it will show `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

I checked the log, and this is caused by connection issues with JMS and database. For my rest controllers testing, I do not need any of them. But their configuration is defined in the application.properties file and it will be loaded in the SpringBootTest, how can I use a different application.properties file for the testing purpose?

Comment: using @ActiveProfiles https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Answer (score 1):

we can use @TestPropertySource or @PropertySource to load the properties file.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:properties.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CartLoadApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works after I put application.properties file in the test directory

```
src/test/resources/application.properties
```